# Copy and pasting data in next empty cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to build a kind of database of documents that have been printed.
I now have a worksheet, in which I input data, and then I print that file and delete all columns using VBA.

To make a database which shows which numbers have already been printed previously, i want to copy the data to a new workbook (called 'Database').

The data is in the following cells:

Number: Cell D8

Date 1: Cell I2

Date 2: Cell E5

Variable 1: P9

Variable 2: P12

The numbers and dates are always present, the variables not. These only show sometimes.
I want it to show up like this:

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11VOM.png)

I have the following to find out what the first empty row is, so I can start pasting the data in the example below only for the 'Number', but I cannot get it to paste. Anyone know what I should change?

```
Dim nextEmptyCell As Range

Set nextEmptyCell = Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(nextEmptyCell.EntireRow) = 0
    
    Set nextEmptyCell = nextEmptyCell.Offset(1)
    
Loop



Worksheets("Database").Range(nextEmptyCell) = Range("D8").Value
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `nextEmptyCell` is a range so no need to wrap it in a range.

Comment: ok thanks! How can I change the last part to get it to work without a range statement then?

Comment: `nextEmptyCell.value = Range("D8").Value`

Comment: Thank you! But when I try it like this, i get a compile error: Sub or Function not defined. Is there a mistake in this? 



Sub Copy_Database()

Dim nextEmptyCell As Range
    
Set nextEmptyCell = Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(nextEmptyCell.EntireRow) = 0
        
Set nextEmptyCell = nextEmptyCell.Offset(1)
 
Loop


nextEmptyCell.Value = Range("D8").Value

End Sub